# "Shot" vs "shot at"

Tags: verbs, transitivity

In The Cambridge Grammar of The English Language (Huddleston & Pullum, 2002), "shoot" belongs a special category of verb, conative verbs: that is, verbs that may be used intransitively to express an unsuccessful attempt. Consider:

[i.] I shot the bird. 
[ii.] I shot at the bird.

The version with "at" implies that I may have missed: cf. [iii.] "I shot at the bird *but it flew away*".

My question is: can I say [iii.] to imply that I did hit the bird, but it didn't actually die and managed to fly away?

Comment: For example, [this article](http://www.fox2detroit.com/news/local-news/homeowner-shot-in-thumb-during-home-invasion-in-garden-city) reads "The homeowner says he got up and, when he saw the first suspect, the suspect **shot at him and hit him in the hand**." Also, the authors of CGEL clearly say that such intransitives are used to imply endeavor, not necessarily failure (although that's one of the possible outcomes of an attempt), so it all checks out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *shot* the bird, you hit it, no question.

If you *shot at* the bird, you *might* have hit it but this construction can also be used to imply that you missed (though the bird's status may simply be unknown).